# BlackBerry library with UI

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry-10

I'm developing apps for BlackBerry 10 in Java. All apps to perform any operations requires user to be logged in. In order to avoid duplicating login form components and logic responsible for authentication I would like to create library for login process. 
The idea is to have UI embedded in library, and then others apps will use library jar file and implemented API in order to invoke login UI. When the user will be successfully authenticated, then returned autn token will be used to perform operations specific to app.

What are possible solutions to embed UI in library? Is there any other way to avoid implementing login functionality in each app? I was also thinking of creating separate app just for login and then other apps will perform temporary redirect to this app in order to get auth token.

Thanks for response.

Comment: You said "I'm developing apps for BlackBerry 10 in Java".  Are you aware that Java is not supported on the BB10 platform?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. What language do you recommend to keep backwards compatibility? In order words I would like to develop app which could be run on BB 10 and previous version as well. Is it possible?